# how to set a windows PC to automatically detect proxy setting

Tags: windows, proxy

i have a domain environment and squid proxy server is configured on domain.but some users also work from other networks and also on our domain network.
i searched for scripts that automatically detect proxy setting.
but i want that wherever users connect on any network.by running the script that PC detect the network setting accordingly.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance.
the scripts is as follows:
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable') DO SET currentProxy=%%B
rem ECHO currentProxy=%currentProxy%

if %currentProxy%==0x1 (
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
echo Proxy Disabled
) else (
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
echo Proxy Enabled
  )

pause

Comment: Try reading a bit about WPAD, it might be exactly what you're looking for: http://blog.ninjatek.co.za/2010/11/proxy-autodetection-using-pac-file-and.html

Comment: i have configured Proxy.pac file on my domain mechines and on their web browsers.it works fine.
Code is below:

function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "192.168.10.0", "255.255.255.0"))
return "PROXY 192.168.10.2:3128";
else
return "DIRECT";
}

we have also C# developers in our environment.so when they debug their project in google chrome.its blocking their local host traffic.
if you have any solution please help me.
any help will be appreciated.
waiting for your kind response.

Comment: I think you should add this: if(isInNet(host,"127.0.0.1","255.255.255.0"))
  {
    return "DIRECT";
  }